# Android Studio AndroidManifest not found after moving project

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

Recently, I moved my Android Studio Flutter project to another location in my computer by closing the project in Android Studio and then opening it in its new location. This was the error that appeared in my console when I try to run my project again.

What do I need to do?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 3 XL in debug mode...
ERROR: dump failed because resource AndroidManifest.xml not found
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed
  Command: /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /Users/user/Desktop/Coding Projects/Work/Smart Weighing Scale/Mobile App/loadcell_app/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Comment: If you have an <activity-alias> in your AndroidManifest.xml it's probably this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80532

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all check `AndroidMainfest.xml` in project's android folder then please try with `flutter clean` command in terminal (It's located at the bottom of Android Studio) and then `flutter create .`

Comment: thanks a lot,This solution solved my problem